# Dropbox on Debian EAGAIN error on NTFS share

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, dropbox

I am experiencing some weird problems, when using dropbox on my Debian install:

- I run Debian with testing repositories enabled
- I have Dropbox installed from the website
- My dropbox-location is on a shared partition that is formatted with NTFS

I mount the dropbox-location in my fstab with the following line:

```
UUID=662058B320588C45 /media/ntfs-data ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=users 0 0
```

This provides me with read/write permissions on the drive - and as
long as I use a filemanager or console (or any other program) to
access the drive it works.

After setting up my dropbox to access the already existing location on this
drive it indexed nearly all files and then stopped with the message:

```
Downloading 38 files ...
```

I tried to check what is happening by attaching `strace` to the process which
yields the following results (this is an excerpt only, as the message keep on
appearing):

```
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 3, 496) = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x9ee784, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 49446674, {1372094398, 476504000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x9ee804, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x9ee800, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x9ee840, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x9ee7c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x9ee784, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x9ee780, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x9ee7c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x9ee784, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 49446680, {1372094398, 476765000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x9ee804, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x9ee800, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x9ee840, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x9ee7c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x9ee784, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x9ee780, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x9ee7c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x9ee784, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 49446687, {1372094398, 477169000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x9ee804, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x9ee800, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x9ee7c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
futex(0x9ee784, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x9ee780, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x9ee7c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{"5\30\4\0\26\10@\1[\0@\1\17\0\17\0=\0\4\0[\0@\1\0\0\0\0\17\0\17\0"..., 96}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 96
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{"$\30\1\0&\10\2\0\341\0\0\0", 12}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 12
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(12, "\1\1;U\0\0\0\0\341\0\0\0\177\0\300\0\246\5S\1\246\5S\1\24\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 32
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{"&\30\2\0\177\0\300\0", 8}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 8
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(12, "\1\1<U\0\0\0\0\341\0\0\0G\0`\2\246\5S\1\246\0*\1\24\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 32
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{"&\30\2\0G\0`\2", 8}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 8
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(12, "\1\1=U\0\0\0\0\341\0\0\0N\0`\2\246\5S\1\244\0*\1\24\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 32
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{"&\30\2\0N\0`\2", 8}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 8
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(12, "\1\1>U\0\0\0\0\341\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\246\5S\1\244\0\25\1\24\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 32
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{"%\30\1\0", 4}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 4
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(12, 0x33b3ae4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 3, 496  C-c C-c^C <unfinished ...>
Process 5687 detached
```

I already ran `ntfsck`:

```
sudo ntfsck /dev/sdb1
Unsupported: replay_log()
Unsupported: check_volume()
Checking 219648 MFT records.
Unsupported cases found.
```

Rebooting into Windows and running chkdsk did not solve the error neither.

Anybody has any idea what this is / how I can fix it?

Comment: What is fd 12? `lsof -p dropbox_pid` or `ls -l /proc/dropbox_pid/fd` will tell you... I suspect this isn't the relevant error. Also, when you say it stopped, what do you mean? That's a normal message, it should be downloading. Did you get an icon in the systray?

Comment: @derobert Ah thanks those are some great pointers in general :) Unfortunately `fd` `12` and `13` both simply say `socket:[13607]` and `socket:[14390]`. They both have the same information in `fdinfo` `cat /proc/5687/fdinfo/13
pos: 0
flags: 02004002`. With "it stopped" I mean, that I can still see the tray icon and the "sync" arrows, but it does never complete - and when I strace it, it always produces the same messages and the `dropbox` process eats up 100% CPU on one core.

Comment: What version of Debian and Dropbox are you using?

Comment: @slm I am running Debian `wheezy` but switched to `testing` repositories (kernel: `3.9-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.9.6-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`). My dropbox client is version `2.2.8` (just downloaded the newest release, but the problem persists). There doesn't seem to be a way to find out what the other endpoint to a UNIX socket is? I would really like to know what is blocking the call.

Comment: @Gjallar - I don't know of a way to do it, doesn't mean it's not possible though. I would be scrutinizing the versions of the `ntfs-3g` still though. There were a lot of threads discussing issues with that software stack. Sounded a bit buggy to me still, so I wouldn't be surpirsed if that was where the issue lied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

The solution that ultimately solved the problem was #4.

#### 1. alternate /etc/fstab options

I've found a couple of people claiming that they're able to do what you're trying to do and did not see any mention of problems similar to yours. The only difference I could find was the `/etc/fstab` mount they were using. I'd try the following:

```
UUID=662058B320588C45 /media/ntfs-data ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

If that doesn't work I found this specifically, you'd have to adjust for your locale, but I don't see why you'd need it, to be honest:

```
UUID=662058B320588C45 /media/ntfs-data ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_GB.UTF-8 0 0
```

#### 2. $HOME/Dropbox as a link

Here's another method that I've seen used where instead of using the Dropbox folder from the NTFS partition directly, they're using a link created in `$HOME/Dropbox` which points to the Dropbox folder on the NTFS partition.

```
$ ln -s /media/ntfs-data/Windows/User/<username>/Dropbox /home/<username>/Dropbox
```

Not sure why this would matter but it's entirely possible that the Dropbox application would then view the NTFS share as just a EXT3/4 directory given it's accessing it through the Unix link created by the `ln` command.

#### 3. Latest version of Dropbox?

I'd confirm that you're using the latest version of the Dropbox client. You can [find updated version here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx). The [release notes are here](https://www.dropbox.com/release_notes) as well.

In general I've found it better to use the downloadable versions of Dropbox rather than anyone that's included in my distros' repositories.

Also I've used the instructions for installing Dropbox from the Unofficial Dropbox Wiki when doing installations from the command-line. The topic's titled: [Install Dropbox In An Entirely Text-Based Linux Environment](http://new.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment).

#### 4. mount options to ntfs-3g

Just add the correct masks for files and folders to the `/etc/fstab` entry (this will make the ntfs drive more compatible with Linux in all cases):

```
UUID=662058B320588C45 /media/ntfs ntfs-3g id=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0
```

#### References

- [UBUNTU / WINDOWS SHARING A DROPBOX FOLDER ON NTFS](http://www.andrewbolster.info/2010/01/ubuntu-windows-sharing-a-dropbox-folder-on-ntfs/)

Comment: I tried the symlinking solution already and it did not work. I just checked the fstab solutions and unfortunately they don't help either. Thanks for the pointers though.

Comment: In the end it actually seems to have been solved by fiddeling enough with my `fstab`: however, the only working solution was this one `UUID=662058B320588C45 /media/ntfs ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0` that I found in the Arch Wiki under the `ntfs-3g` entry (it adds directory and file permissions): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G

Comment: @Gjallar - glad you resolved your issue. Write it up as an answer and accept it. Good find BTW, I saw that page before but hadn't noticed the `dmask`/`umask` switches. I knew it was something with `ntfs-3g` 8-).